# Setting hyphenationFactor on Label

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

on android, TextView's have a BREAK_STRATEGY_HIGH_QUALITY as default BreakStrategy set (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setBreakStrategy(int)).
iOS has a hyphenationFactor property with a default value of 0.0. This means hyphenation is disabled (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1535553-hyphenationfactor):
Is it possible to set the hyphenationFactor to 1.0 on xamarin forms labels for ios?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do you mean want to set the hyphenationFactor to 1.0 for iOS when running on android device, and later will show the effect when running on iOS device?

Comment: Sorry,  i should read what i write before saving.

Comment: Okey, I will suggest that using web server to store the status, because android device can not communite with iOS device directly even it's a forms application.

Comment: If i have a xamarin forms label with the text "Gesamtmarkt" for example and two lines and the text doesn't fit the width. On android the text becomes  
Gesamt-\n
markt.  
On iOS the text becomes:
Gesamtmar\n  
kt
Thats because on android hyphenation was enabled by default. On iOS it was disabled. So i want to enable hyphenation on iOS too. \n stands for a new line.

Comment: Okey, You can use [custom label render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) to only modify in iOS solution and not need to do something with Android solution.

Comment: Thank you. That was my intention. Do you have some sample code for manipulation NSMutableParagraphStyle with xamarin forms. I'm not sure where i should start.

Comment: I have updated answer, you can have a look at it when you have time. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to **[Customizing an Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)** document to create a custom Lable in Xamarin Forms.

As follows:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
}
```

Then in iOS solution, create a **CustomLabelRenderer** class, and using **NSMutableParagraphStyle** in iOS solution as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MyLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace AppShellTest.iOS
{
    class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
            paragraphStyle.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            var attributes=  new UIStringAttributes()
            {
                ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red,
                KerningAdjustment = 3
            };
            attributes.ParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle;
            var myText = new NSAttributedString("Hello, world", attributes);
            Control.AttributedText = myText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  
I changed your sample a litte bit, because i don't want to override other syle attributes:  
`protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e) {`
`base.OnElementChanged(e);`

`if(e.NewElement == null) {`
` return;`
`}`
`var style = Control?.AttributedText?.GetAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle, 0, out _);`
`if(style == null) {`
` return;`
`}`
`var paragraphStyle = (NSMutableParagraphStyle)style;`
`paragraphStyle.HyphenationFactor = 1.0F;`
`}`
It is possible or you see a mistake with my code?

Comment: @Saftpresse99 I'm not sure, you can have a try to check whehter it works.If only want to modify `HyphenationFactor`, just changing this property will be fine.